# how do I log the specs when the tests are successful in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, automated-tests, mocha.js, meanjs

As, mocha logs the specs string if the test is successful.
for the below test suite,

```
describe("capitalize", function() {
   it("capitalizes single words", function() { /* … */});
   it("makes the rest of the string lowercase", function() {
     expect(capitalize("javaScript")).to.equal("Javascript");
   });
});
```

firing the ***npm test*** command would log the following,

```
capitalize
✓ capitalizes single words
✓ makes the rest of the string lowercase
2 passing (10ms)
```

The same when written with jasmine would simply log two green dots denoting that the tests were successful.
So, is there any way to achieve the mocha like logs ?
As the official docs do not help in this regard !

Comment: Doesn't the SpecRunner.html do what you ask for? I can see all the specs there and a tick if they passed.

Comment: I've actually downloaded jasmine using npm and I did read about the SpecRunner.html file but I don't find one in my globally/locally installed jasmine module.Am I missing out something ? one thing that I want to bring to your notice is that I'm using the CLI to run my tests and not a browser instance !

Comment: I think specRunner is to be used with plain javascript, I'm using 
Express.js on top of Node.js.

Comment: Yes, I think SpecRunner.html is for plain Javascript. Sorry, I don't know how it'd work from CLI in node.js.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter), it is a jasmine reporter that display output this way:

```
Spec started

  first suite
    ✓ should be ok
    ✗ should failed
      - Expected true to be false.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Karma to run your tests you can accomplish this. I use a reporter called `karma-mocha-reporter`. You can find more details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter).It produces output in the console like this:

[image]